# TFS http://localhost:8080/Services/V1.0/ServerStatus.asmx is not available

Tags: web-services, tfs

Its weird, I can browse

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/
```

from the TFS Server (2010) machine and its fine. However, I am unable to connect it from the client. I am using IP to connect from. It has been working fine in the past but not sure what happened and its not accessible anymore.

`http://localhost:8080/Services/V1.0/ServerStatus.asmx` doesn't browse anything even on server itself. Just says nothing exists like this.
any idea what I should be looking to fix the issue?

Thanks
Sameers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is located at:

```
http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx
```

It looks like you are missing the collection name in your url.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Now my issue is, I can browse this on the TFS server machine itself, however, from another machine, I can't browse it. Browser spins for a long time and finally get nothing (page can't be displayed). Can you suggest me something that where should I look for the problem. I can browse using IP address of the server on the server itself http://xx.yy.zz.aa:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx but can't do that from outside the server. Thanks

Comment: I just tried to access the service on my tfs server from my machine and had no problem so it sounds like something else is preventing you accessing it.